# Fill a list from a generator

Tags: python

How do I make a list out of the first 'n' items returned by a generator?

(I know this is easy and I could RTFM, but sometimes it's easier to POFSO.)

Comment: I have to admit, I dunno what POFSO is, but RTFM is definitely better in this case.

Comment: @bereal I disagree.  In this case POFSO probably saved me about ten minutes, which is well worth the downvotes.

Comment: Many people admit readily that this is the place for those of us, "too lazy to RTFM". Honesty counts. +1

Comment: @gcbenison Ok, your ten minutes apparently worth more than other people's 5 minutes * 3 answers + 2 minutes * 23 views = ... Wait, will ask at math.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
foo = [x for x in itertools.islice(generator, n)]
```

...assuming that your generator is named `generator` and `n` is the number of elements you'd like.

The [itertools library](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) has a lot of useful glue like this.

Answer (score 3):

There is [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) command in `itertools` module which does the thing:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> iterator = itertools.count() #just counter from 0 to infinity
>>> list(itertools.islice(iterator,10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
it = (i for i in [1,2,3,4])
sliced = islice(it,2)
for i in it:
    print i

# output:
# 1
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generator that fills a list with the square of all fibonacci numbers in the chosen range:

```
def fibonacci_numbers(nums):
    x, y = 0, 1
    for _ in range(nums):
        x, y = y, x+y
        yield x

def square(nums):
    for num in nums:
        yield num**2

a = input("Write the number of elements: ")
a = int(a)
list1 = [x for x in square(fibonacci_numbers(a))]
print(list1)
```